# invalid literal for int() with base 10: when using foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a private chat with channels, I'm encountering an issue when passing an username to the url.

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'username'

This error probably occurs because I'm using a ForeignKey because everything worked well using a ChatField and I want to know how I can resolve this issue.

**models.py :**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator', null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def new_room(request):
    try:
        #get the submited product object
        gig = Gig.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('inGig_id'))
    except Gig.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')

    creator = request.user
    Room.objects.get_or_create(gig=gig, creator=creator)
    return redirect(commenting_room, gig=gig.id, creator=creator)


def commenting_room(request, gig, creator):
    room = Room.objects.get(gig=gig, creator=creator) #error occurs here
    ...
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^room/(?P<gig>\d+)/(?P<creator>\w+)/$', views.commenting_room, name='commenting_room_detail'),
```

Any suggestion on how I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: @UrielEli on `creator` field

Comment: @Sayse it's not since it works with a CharField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the creator id to `.get` and not the username text passed via the url, since `creator` is a ForeignKey field in `Room`:

```
def commenting_room(request, gig, creator):
    creator_id = User.objects.get(username=creator).id
    room = Room.objects.get(gig=gig, creator=creator_id)
```